# Event on visual element destruction in flash builder?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4, flash-builder, flex4.5

I need to run some code when a panel is destroyed. The code is simple, I have some Background tasks while it is opened, but need to stop them when closed.

I have a Close button for the panel, and I stop the BG Tasks when the user wants to close the panel, the problem is that they have access to a top menu bar too and can jump to another application module/part throught it, so, the user can exit the panel (when exiting, the panel is automatically destroyed) but the panel close event code is not executed because the close button was not pressed.

One solution could be to inherit from panel and add a post step method that is called when swapping modules, etc... So, if the user wants to move to another place through the menu bar, my system will first call sometihng like PreEnd() method on the panel and everything will be solved. But, is there any event that I could catch from the panel when it is destroyed to accomplish this? I have been checking the documentation but couldn't find anything useful to achieve what I explain.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try adding an eventListener to the `removedFromStage` event or the `hide` event, depending on what happens to the panel when the user loads another module. My guess is you want the `removedFromStageEvent`. You can run your close event code from there (if it's not already running from the `close` event).